# Get payment total minus amount received

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, group-by, common-table-expression

I have two tables.

1.Invoice

```
invoice_Id  invoice_no  client_id   date        total_price    
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
2           INV00001    9           2014-10-15  200.00   
7           INV00002    9           2014-10-16  560.00   
8           INV00003    9           2014-10-21  100.00   
11          INV00004    9           2014-10-27  101.00
```

2.Invoice_payment

```
InvPayment_id   client_id   Invoice_Id  receipt_no  payment_date    amount_received discount
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
6               9           8           REC00002    2014-10-31      5.00            0.00
```

Now I want to get Total Amount Due by Client by totalling the invoice amounts and subtracting any amounts received.

Expected Result:

```
client_id   Total_price    Due_Amount
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
9           961.00         956.00
```

NOTES:

1. There will be zero rows if no payments are taken to date.
2. There could be multiple rows if more than one payment is taken.

Here is what I have tried:

```
;WITH cte (clientid, invoiceid,  paid, disc)
As
(
    Select client_id clientId, invoice_Id invoiceId,  sum(amount_received) paid, sum(discount) disc
    From tbl_Invoice_Payment
    Group by invoice_id, client_id
)
Select I.client_id, invoice_Id, invoice_no, I.due_date
,SUM(I.total_price), Isnull(SUM(paid), 0) Paid, (SUM(Total_price) - Isnull(SUM(paid),0) - Isnull(SUM(disc),0)) Balance
--,I.total_price, Isnull(paid, 0) Paid, (Total_price - Isnull(paid,0) - Isnull(disc,0)) Balance
From tbl_invoice I Left join cte On I.client_id = cte.clientId 
        And I.invoice_id = cte.invoiceid
        left join tbl_client C on C.client_id = I.client_id
group by I.client_id, invoice_Id, invoice_no, due_date, account_type, company_name, total_price, paid, disc
order by company_name
```

But it's not working as intended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using a CTE, you can simply add a subquery to return the result of payments made and subtract that value from the total:

### [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/17ad7/2)

**Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE Invoice
    ([invoice_Id] int, [invoice_no] varchar(8), [client_id] int, 
     [date] datetime, [total_price] decimal(5,2));

INSERT INTO Invoice
    ([invoice_Id], [invoice_no], [client_id], [date], [total_price])
VALUES
    (2, 'INV00001', 9, '2014-10-15 00:00:00', 200.00),
    (7, 'INV00002', 9, '2014-10-16 00:00:00', 560.00),
    (8, 'INV00003', 9, '2014-10-21 00:00:00', 100.00),
    (11, 'INV00004', 9, '2014-10-27 00:00:00', 101.00);

CREATE TABLE Invoice_Payment
    ([InvPayment_id] int, [client_id] int, [Invoice_Id] int, [receipt_no] varchar(8), 
     [payment_date] datetime, [amount_received] decimal(5,2), [discount] int);

INSERT INTO Invoice_Payment
    ([InvPayment_id], [client_id], [Invoice_Id], [receipt_no], [payment_date], 
     [amount_received], [discount])
VALUES
    (6, 9, 8, 'REC00002', '2014-10-31 00:00:00', 5.00, 0.00);
```

**Query to generate output:**:

```
SELECT  i.client_id , SUM(i.total_price) AS Total_price,
        SUM(i.total_price) - ( SELECT   SUM(ip.amount_received)
                               FROM     dbo.Invoice_Payment ip
                               WHERE    i.client_id = ip.client_id
                             ) AS DueAmount
FROM    dbo.Invoice i
WHERE   client_id = 9
GROUP BY client_id
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/17ad7/2/0)**:

```
| CLIENT_ID | TOTAL_PRICE | DUEAMOUNT |
|-----------|-------------|-----------|
|         9 |         961 |       956 |
```

Comment: Great. There're some modifications in the query but I have made it work. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please select the values you want. The problem is related to grouping.

In the `group by` clause `I.client_id`, `invoice_Id`, `invoice_no`, `due_date`, `account_type`, `company_name`, `total_price`, `paid`, `disc` this much fields are specified. `invoice_Id`, `invoice_no` prevent grouping which you need. Remove both `invoice_Id` and `invoice_no` from `select` and `group by` and try again.